# Send email using python with Gmail as provider. Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to send emails using `python` with `gmail` as the provider. The code is as follows:

```
import smtplib


def send_email():
    email_address = 'xxx@gmail.com'
    email_password = 'xxx'

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_address, email_password)
        sub= 'sdgsdg'
        msg = 'sdfsf'
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(sub, msg)
        server.sendmail(email_address, email_address, message)
        server.quit()
        print('Success: Email sent!')
    except:
        print('Email failed to send.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_email()
```

I am executing using `Python 3.6.2` on `Windows 10`. The code used to execute for long time and the email is not being sent. The code never stops executing and I am force stopping it. Could any one point out whats the problem with the function?. Definitely, I have enabled `less secure apps` in `gmail`. I think the code never moves forward from `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')`.

Comment: Okay i think there problem is with internet provider. When I tried using my hotspot it worked flawless.

Answer (score 1):

I maked an "auto mail sender" what will take a lot of files of products and mails, auto correct some of wrongs typed mails, auto variate the subject and messages base on specific algorithm and supported external language to...

This is just a part from my code maybe is helping...

```py
#// - You need to set "Allow less secure apps: ON" (go to link below).
#//                 - https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
#// Is work and with out that "allow..." but is more ok to set it.

# Imports
import smtplib, time

# Language
error_title = "ERROR"
send_error = "I'm waiting {idle} and I will try again."
send_error_mail = "Mail invalid"
send_error_char = "Invalid character"
send_error_connection_1_2 = "Connection problem..."
send_error_connection_2_2 = "Gmail server is down or internet connection is instabil."
login_browser = "Please log in via your web browser and then try again."
login_browser_info = "That browser and this software shood have same IP connection first time."

# Gmaild ID fro login
fromMail = "your_id@gmail.com"
fromPass = "your_password"

# To ho to send mails
mailTo = [
    "test@me.com",
    "test_2@ymail.com"
]

# Some configurations
mailDelay = 15
exceptionDelay = 180

# SEND MAILS
def send_mail(thisSubject="Just a subject", thisMessage="This is just a simple message..."):
    # If still have mails to send
    while len(mailTo) != 0:
        sendItTo = mailTo[0]    # Memorise what mail will be send it (debug purpose)
        try:
            # Connect to the server
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()

            # Sign In
            server.login(fromMail, fromPass)

            # Set the message
            message = f"Subject: {thisSubject}\n{thisMessage}"

            # Send one mail
            server.sendmail(fromMail, mailTo.pop(0), message)

            # Sign Out
            server.quit()

        # If is a problem
        except Exception as e:
            # Convert error in a string for som checks
            e = str(e)

            # Show me if...
            if "The recipient address" in e and "is not a valid" in e:
                print(f"\n>>> {send_error_mail} [//> {sendItTo}\n")
            elif "'ascii'" in e and "code can't encode characters" in e:
                print(f"\n>>> {send_error_char} [//> {sendItTo}\n")
            elif "Please" in e and "log in via your web browser" in e:
                print(f"\n>>> {login_browser}\n>>>  - {login_browser_info}")
                break
            elif "[WinError 10060]" in e:
                if "{idle}" in send_error:
                    se = send_error.split("{idle}"); seMsg = f"{se[0]}{exceptionDelay} sec.{se[1]}"
                else:
                    seMsg = send_error
                print(f"\n>>> {send_error_connection_1_2}\n>>> {send_error_connection_2_2}")
                print(f">>> {seMsg}\n")
                # Wait 5 minutes
                waitTime = exceptionDelay - mailDelay
                if waitTime <= 0:
                    waitTime = exceptionDelay
                time.sleep(waitTime)
            else:
                if "{idle}" in send_error:
                    se = send_error.split("{idle}"); seMsg = f"{se[0]}{exceptionDelay} sec.{se[1]}"
                else:
                    seMsg = send_error
                print(f">>> {error_title} <<<", e)
                print(f">>> {seMsg}\n")
                # Wait 5 minutes
                time.sleep(exceptionDelay)

        # If are still mails wait before to send another one
        if len(mailTo) != 0:
            time.sleep(mailDelay)

send_mail()
```

(*I can give you the hole code ig you want to play with it why not*)

Comment: Thanks for the offer!. How would you like to share it?

Comment: Give hmm... That is interesting because I can not write a private message (I'm new in this "community", write me on discord: #7570)